# Laravel - Where on relation from different database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to apply where condition on joined table, but I'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cts.plant' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `tbl_complaint` where exists (select * from `tbl_plant` where `tbl_complaint`.`made_in_plant` = `tbl_plant`.`plant_id` and `sap_code` = 99999) order by `created` desc limit 50 offset 0)

My model classes looks something like this:

Main Model

```
    class Complaint extends Model {
        protected $connection= 'first';
        protected $table = 'complaint';
        protected $primaryKey = 'complaint_id';

    public function  customerPlant() {
        return $this->hasOne(Plant::class, 'plant_id', 'customer_plant_id')
                    ->select('plant_id', 'sap_code', 'plant_name');
    }
}
```

Connected Model

```
class Plant extends Model {
    protected $connection= 'second';
    protected $table = 'plant';
    protected $primaryKey = 'plant_id';

    public function getKeyName() {
        return 'plant_id';
    }
}
```

Data retrieval:

```
    $query = Complaint::with([
        'madeInPlantId']
    $query = Complaint::whereHas('madeInPlant', function($query){
        $query->where('sap_code','=','99999');
    });
    $query->get();
```

I think that problem is I'm not specifying that connected table is in another database.

Comment: can you post the connection strings used?

Comment: why do you need connection strings ? Also, i need to say, without wherehas clausule everithing works fine, im getting record with joined data from another table

Comment: because, i just want to confirm something, we have a setup similar to yours before. the tables are on one server but different databases, all we have to do is prefix the database name to the table name `protected $table = 'database1.plant';`

Comment: Can you include the error as text in the question? Dark text in tiny font on black background is quite unreadable

Comment: i edited the question with error text

Comment: i see that the error in my case is that Eloquent is trying to retrieve data from cts database, but table plant is in another db

Comment: @Joe thanks a lot, your suggestion actually worked. if you create an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your tables are on the same server but different databases, you can do this.

```
class Complaint extends Model {
    protected $table = 'cts.complaint';
    protected $primaryKey = 'complaint_id';

    public function  customerPlant(){
        return $this->hasOne(Plant::class, 'plant_id', 'customer_plant_id')
                ->select('plant_id', 'sap_code', 'plant_name');
    }
}

class Plant extends Model{
    protected $table = 'otherdatabase.plant';
    protected $primaryKey = 'plant_id';

    public function getKeyName() {
        return 'plant_id';
    }
}
```